# Play audio on selection list in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm developing a simple app where the list of sounds is available and by tapping on it that sound should play.
For that, I've created below SwiftUI view. But `didSet()` of `selectedSound` is never being called.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SoundList: View {
    let category: Category
    @State private var selectedSound: String? {
        didSet {
            if let selectedSound {
                AudioManager.shared.playAudio(withFilename: selectedSound)
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(selectedSound ?? "N/A") // Just to check if selection is working or not
            List(category.sounds, id: \.self, selection: $selectedSound) { sound in
                Text(sound)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(category.name)
    }
}

struct SoundList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SoundList(category: Category.getAllData().first!)
    }
}
```

I'm sure my AudioManager class is working fine, so there is no any faulty code for playing audio.
What Am I missing here? Stateful variables never called it's `didSet()`? if yes then what will be workaround this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `didSet`, use `.onChange(of:){}` instead.
Like this:

```
    @State private var selectedSound: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(selectedSound ?? "N/A") // Just to check if selection is working or not
            List(category.sounds, id: \.self, selection: $selectedSound) { sound in
                Text(sound)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(category.name)

        // Here:
        .onChange(of: selectedSound) { value in
            if let value {
                AudioManager.shared.playAudio(withFilename: value)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any note that, where should I use '$' and where shouldn't?

Comment: You use $ when the function requires a Binding variable. This usually means that the function will change the value of the variable - in you example, List will change the value of the selectedSound. .onChange(of:) just needs to read the value, so it’s not a Binding (no $).